# Ruby selenium-webdriver (LoadError) when automating script

Tags: ruby, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I created a ruby-based selenium test that navigates out to a site and validates that a page element is present.  The script runs properly when executed from the command line but produces the following error when run via either Automator or Cronjob:

```
/Library/Ruby/Site/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require': cannot load such file -- selenium-webdriver (LoadError)
from  Library/Ruby/Site/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
from /Users/xxxxxxx/workspace/xxxxxxxx/script.rb:2:in `<main>'
```

Based on research, I have uninstalled and reinstalled the *selenium-webdriver* gem as sudo but continue to receive the error.

My environment setup is as follows, Mac OSX running ruby 2.2.1p85 (2015-02-26 revision 49769) [x86_64-darwin15].  With the following gems installed:

```
*** LOCAL GEMS ***

bigdecimal (1.2.7, 1.2.6)
bundler (1.10.6)
bundler-unload (1.0.2)
childprocess (0.5.8)
executable-hooks (1.3.2)
ffi (1.9.10)
gem-wrappers (1.2.7)
io-console (0.4.3)
json (1.8.3, 1.8.1)
mini_portile (0.6.2)
multi_json (1.11.2)
nokogiri (1.6.6.2)
nokogirl (1.0)
psych (2.0.15, 2.0.8)
rake (10.4.2)
rdoc (4.2.0)
rubygems-bundler (1.4.4)
rubyzip (1.1.7)
rvm (1.11.3.9)
selenium-webdriver (2.48.1)
websocket (1.2.2)
```

Any ideas?

Comment: It does look, like there is some user right issue... . Is the selenium gem now availiable for all uses? i.e. is it installed with the sudo command? If so, than uninstall it and just run gem install ..., or use a Gemfile and run bundle install

Comment: I have attempted uninstall and reinstall (via sudo) numerous times with no avail.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using a ruby version manager? It seems like it is using your default ruby, so if you installed the gem within the scope of the version manager, it won't be seen on system ruby

Comment: Yes, I'm using _rvm_.  Any idea of an easy way around this issue without having to remove the use of _rvm_?

Comment: You can set the default ruby to the ruby that is installed with rvm. Or use a .ruby-version and a .gemset file in your project. This way, rvm changes the installed ruby to the ruby and gemset specified in the file.

Comment: A common place to place the sourcing of rvm is inside of your ~/.bash_profile. See if that makes a difference